# Private Route on refresh is including the Redirect Route

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router-dom

I am trying to do a simple PrivateRoute in ReactJS and originally when I wrote the PrivateRoute function it would not redirect to the component it was set to go to.

This is the original `PrivateRoute` component

```
 import React from 'react';
 import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
 const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, authenticated , ...rest}) => {
    return (
    <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
    authenticated === true
      ? <Component {...props} />
      : <Redirect to='/login' />
  )}/>
  )
 }



 export default PrivateRoute;
```

I then edited the `PrivateRoute` Component to get rid of the `{...rest}` prop, and it worked fine, it redirected to the protected page. But whenever I edit the `PrivateRoute` Components and the browser refreshes they include both the page I edited and the Redirected Page as if I were logged out and logged in at the same time. In Hindsight the `/login` page I redirect if `authenticated` is not true would be on the top page and the Protected component would be right below it on the same page.

Here is the component that works before any refresh of the new page

```
 import React from 'react';
 import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
 const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, authenticated ,}) => 
  {
    return (
    <Route render={(props) => (
    authenticated === true
      ? <Component {...props} />
      : <Redirect to='/login' />
  )}/>
  )
 }



 export default PrivateRoute;
```

any help would be greatly appreciated and here is my App.js

```
     <BrowserRouter>
      <Route path="/" component = {LandingPage} exact/>
      <Route path="/login" component={Login} exact/>
      <Route path="/register" component={Register} exact/>
      <PrivateRoute path="/dash" component={Dash}  authenticated={authenticated}/>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out why I had the problem that I did in `App.js` file I set the authenticated state to false and did not set a timeout function which solved my problem

Comment: I'm having that issue. can you show me your code in App.js.